# How do I tell a class to create unique sub-classes

Tags: c++, class, subclass

I have defined a class called `Instrument` which I initialise by calling a function in the class to it the name of the Instrument to put up on the display.

I now create two Instruments:

```
Instrument Organ
Instrument Piano
```

I also have another class called `Screen` which handles changing values such as volume and putting those values on the display.  For example it has a function called `IncValue()` which does what it says.

I want to create subclasses that can be repeated for all Instruments such as :

```
Screen Volume
```

This would declare `int16_t volume` and `IncValue()` would increment the volume, `DecValue()` reduce it.

But how do I create those `Screens` from the `Instrument Class` such that I can do things like

```
Organ.Volume.IncValue()
```

(or -> maybe, I've got totally lost on this level of complexity)
and

```
Piano.Volume.IncValue()
```

and they only work on the relevant Instrument.

Eventually there will be 100s of Instruments declared so I really don't want to declare unique Classes such as `Screen PianoVolume` and `Screen OrganVolume`.

Hope this isn't too long-winded a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting mixed up between classes and objects.  Just have class `Instrument` own an object of class `Screen`.  The rest then follows naturally.

So you might have (expanding on your ideas a little bit):

```
class Screen
{
public:
    void IncValue ();
private:
    int volume;
};

class Instrument
{
public:
    Screen screen;
    ...
};

class Piano : public Instrument
{
    ...
};
```

And then you can do (for example):

```
Piano MyPiano;
MyPiano.screen.IncValue ();
...
```

for any Instrument or subclass of Instrument.